# Regex Exclude Number Within Two Characters of Number

Tags: regex

I have some manually entered data (it's an email subject), and I am trying to extract the correct ID to perform a series of actions with RPA on.

```
RE:'HC=312-822-281' abc2-1234567 7354612
```

I have a regex query:

```
(?<!\d)\d{7}(?!\d)
```

I want to extract `7354612` but not `1234567`.

I want to avoid matching any 7-digit number that is preceded with a hyphen, or a hyphen and a space.

My initial query works 80% of the time, but this hyphen issue is interfering with the other 20%.

Comment: Use `(?<!\S)\d{7}(?!\S)`, see https://regex101.com/r/QBcdMa/1

Comment: This doesn't accommodate for the hyphen?

Comment: This matches a 7-digit number in between whitespace or start/end of string

Comment: But I want to exclude any 7 digit number that is within two characters of a -(hyphen) character. So RE:'HC=312-822-281' abc2- 1234567 7354612 will trick your regex?

Comment: Why will it get tricked?  See https://regex101.com/r/QBcdMa/2, the `1234567` is not directly preceded with `-`. You may also try [`(?<![\d-])\d{7}(?!\d)`](https://regex101.com/r/QBcdMa/3)

Comment: I don't want it to catch 1234567 due to the preceding hyphen

Comment: So what else can be between the hyphen and the number? What are you doing: extracting/replacing/splitting? What is the programming language? Pattern requirements must be provided in the question, too.

Comment: Realistically it will either be nothing or a space. This is manual entered data (it's an email subject). I am then trying to extract the correct id to perform a series of actions with RPA. My initial query works 80% of the time, but this hyphen issue is interfering with the other 20%

Comment: Then why not just add another lookahead? `(?<![\d-])(?<!- )\d{7}(?!\d)`

Comment: Because obviously I'm quite stupid today haha! Thank you for that!

Comment: The question is not bad, if you add all the details I mentioned, it will be possible to reopen it.

Comment: Great, I have edited the question there now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the existing `(?<!\d)` lookbehind to also exclude the position after a hyphen, i.e. `(?<![\d-])`, and add another lookbehind to exclude the hyphen + space context (`(?<!- )` or `(?<!-\s)`):

```
(?<![\d-])(?<!- )\d{7}(?!\d)
(?<![\d-])(?<!-\s)\d{7}(?!\d)
```

Note `\s` matches any whitespace. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QBcdMa/4).

**Details**

- `(?<![\d-])` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is a digit or a hyphen immediately to the left of the current location
- `(?<!-\s)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is a `-` and a space after it immediately to the left of the current location
- `\d{7}` - any seven digits
- `(?!\d)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a digit  immediately to the right of the current location.

**Variations**

With PCRE regex, you may also use

```
-\s*\d{7}(?!\d)(*SKIP)(*F)|(?<!\d)\d{7}(?!\d)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QBcdMa/5), where `-\s*\d{7}(?!\d)(*SKIP)(*F)|` matches `-`, 0+ spaces, seven digits after which there are no more digits and skips that match, only returning matches for the `(?<!\d)\d{7}(?!\d)` pattern.

In .NET, modern JavaScript and PyPi regex in Python, you may use

```
(?<!\d|-\s*)\d{7}(?!\d)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QBcdMa/6). Here, `(?<!\d|-\s*)` negative lookbehind fails the match if there is a digit or `-` + 0 or more whitespace chars immediately to the left of the current position.